# Design - how map Request parameters data to domain model

Tags: java, c#, ruby, domain-driven-design

This is a design question is the same problem in any language.

Guys as you do to map the controller to the domain model?

We have situations in general larger than ... consider the example objects .

situation.1 - We have a request that has all the parameters of the account ;
{ " id" : " 1 " , "name " : "test " , "some " : " xxx " } ............. and other fields .

situation.2 - can request that has to have a certain account parameters , for example in the case of an update;
{" id" , " 1" , "name " , " testUpdated "}

situation.3 - We have a request that has some parameters of the account , others have more like id as user together;
{ " id" : " 1 " , "user " : " xxx " , "service " : " yyy " } in which case each piece of the request will turn an object .

```
public class Account {

private Long id;
private String name ;
private String some ;

}
```

I see a few options ;

1 - Can I get AccountForm in the controller  and set the properties for the Account object and others in CONTROLLER ;

```
+ ok for situation.1 situations 2, and situation.3
+ Separates the requisition of the object domain
- Pollutes the controller with code conversion
- Controller is full of setters .. if a higher class as a large object as a request is very confusing .

controller ( AccountForm from ) {
Account account = new Account ( )
account.setNome form.getNome = ();
account.setSome form.getSome = ();
Other outher = new Other ( ) ;
other.setSome ( form.getSome ( ) ) ;
}
```

2 - Can I get AccountRequest in the controller and have a method in itself as AccountRequest.getAccount ( ) to return a mapped model , in this case the mapping is at own Request object .

```
+ Separates the requisition of the object domain
+ Encapsulates the conversion in a place with easy access .
+ Meets situation.1 situation.2 and situation3 ;
- Request object has two responsibilities represent the request and map to a valid model .

controller ( AccountForm accountRequest ) {
Account account = accountRequest.getAccount ( ) ;
Outher outher accountRequest.getOther = ( ) 
}
```

3 - Can I get the controller Direct Account which had been filled with nulls .

```
+ Eliminate object request
- Serves only situation.1 situation.2 .

controller (Account account ) {
account.someMethod ();
}
```

4 - Outsource this mapping request parameters to another object mapper for request ..

```
+ Isolates logic mapping
- Until complexity for simpler cases are used as standard for all such a find by id .
- One more class for each request ;
```

In the case of API gets worse response has two further classes. speaking in terms of request for response .... AccountRequest, AccountRequestMapper, Account, AccountResponseMapper, AccountResponse ........

I'm doing more testing the Hybrid option 3 for simple cases (find ID or updates) .... with option 2 for example for more complex cases ...

What would be ideal / What is expressive and easy to maintain? Thank you.

Comment: Side note: "controller" have many special meanings in different framework/languages... You may want to clarify what you mean by it in you particular case... Like "controller as it used in classic MVC design pattern" or "controller as in ASP.Net MVC"...

Comment: controller MVC i want to say how map the request parameters to domain model...

Answer (score 1):

Each of your ways listed in your question is technically "correct" :). Whether you choose one of them or use a different approach depends on the complexity of your use case.

Do read through the [DDD bible](http://www.amazon.in/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215) to understand if you even need a Domain model.

Now let us assume that you do and also further **assume** that Account is an aggregate root, then you certainly do not want to be exposing your Domain Model to the external word.

You will probably use a DTO or such to collect enough information about the Account model and then delegate to a factory/builder who will build out the Account AR for you.

Again i would encourage you to read through the book and ascertain if you need the complexity.